# Node.js server side connection to Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a Node.js application with a frontend app and a backend app, the backend will manage the list and "push" an update to the frontend app, the call to the frontend app will trigger a list update so that all clients receive the correct list data.

The problem is on the backend side, when I press the button, I perform an AJAX call, and that AJAX call will perform the following code (trimmed some operations out of it):

```
  Lists.findOne({_id: active_settings.active_id}, function(error, lists_result) {
      var song_list = new Array();
      for (i=0; i < lists_result.songs.length; i++) {
        song_list.push(lists_result.songs[i].ref);
      }
      Song.find({
        '_id': {$in: song_list}
      }, function(error, songs){
        // DO STUFF WITH THE SONGS
        // UPDATE SETTINGS (code trimmed)
        active_settings.save(function(error, updated_settings) {
            list = {
              settings: updated_settings,
            };
            var io = require('socket.io-client');
            var socket = io.connect(config.app_url);
            socket.on('connect', function () {
               socket.emit('update_list', {key: config.socket_key});
            });
            response.json({
                status: true,
                list: list
            });
            response.end();
          }
      });
    });
```

However the response.end never seems to work, the call keeps hanging, further more, the list doesn't always get refreshed so there is an issue with the socket.emit code. And the socket connection stays open I assume because the response isn't ended?

I have never done this server side before so any help would be much appreciated. (the active_settings etc exists)

Answer (score 2):

I see some issues that might or might not be causing your problems:

- `list` isn't properly scoped, since you don't prefix it with `var`; essentially, you're creating a global variable which might get overwritten when there are multiple requests being handled;
- `response.json()` calls `.end()` itself; it doesn't hurt to call `response.end()` again yourself, but not necessary;
- since you're not closing the socket(.io) connection anywhere, it will probably always stay open;
- it sounds more appropriate to not set up a new `socket.io` connection for each request, but just once at your app startup and just re-use that;

Comment: How do I close that connection? The call will only happen once every 4-5 minutes and executed by only one person so the new connection is ok I think

Comment: @romenov try `socket.disconnect()` after you emitted the message (in the `connect` handler)

Comment: I modified it now to this:
socket.on('connect', function() {
console.log('connected');
socket.emit('update_list', {key: config.socket_key}); 
socket.disconnect();
});
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
console.log('disconnecting');
response.end();
});
response.end();
When I execute the first time console outputs: connected, disconnecting but the response.end() still isn't working (the var scope of list has also been fixed)
When I press again (even after refresh etc) it's not giving the connected / disconnecting message anymore. And my call keeps executing and after 2 minutes it gets a 200 OK

Comment: @romenov I think you shouldn't end the response in the `disconnect` handler for the socket; also, try removing the socket.io part for a bit to see if that solves your response problems

Comment: the problem lied with the response.json for some reason.. I removed that and just used response.end(), now the response problem is fixed.. the socket part however is still persistent

Comment: @romenov it might take a while before a socket.io connection is actually disconnected, depending on the server configuration. As for `response.json` not working, that's strange. Is the list very large?